# How do I disable Filtering in a DXL script?

Tags: ibm-doors

I have a script that I'm working and noticed that some objects are being found.  I think I've traced the issue to the fact that the default view has filtering associated with it.  I'd like to know how to disable filtering in DXL or change the view of the module that I've opened to "Standard View"

Answer (score 2):

To turn off the filter:

```
filtering off
```

To change the view in the current module:

```
View v = view("Standard")
load(v)
```

I recommend checking out `Help -> DXL Reference Manual` from inside the DOORS Client. From the index tab you can search all the published functions.

Comment: So I ended up fixing this issue by setting the default view of each module to be "standard".  Your fix here (I believe) only sets the currently opened module (the one running the dxl script) to have the filtering off, not the remote views which is what I need to change.

Comment: It does set the current module view, so you need to use: `current = REMOTE_MODULE` to change which is the current before setting the view. Your solution will work unless someone changes the default view again.

Comment: I have an idea of where you're coming from with this question, so I'll offer two comments:

string setDefaultViewForModule(Module m, string viewName) 
Sets the default view for the specified module to viewName. Returns a null string if the operation succeeds; otherwise, returns an error message.

There is a third optional parameter for the read/share/edit functions. It is a boolean, when true opens the module with the Standard view. Useful when opening modules in DXL and you don't want filters or complicated (and possibly broken) attributes or columns to appear.